# Formula that finds the last non blank cell which is greater than zero in a range

Tags: excel

I have a slight puzzle with an Excel formula and am using it in conjunction with IBM Cognos Disclosure Management which disables VBA so can't use a coded work around as I would normally.

I need a formula that finds the last non blank cell which is greater than zero in a range (Single row)

So for instance:

[image]

In this example I’d expect col F to be returned with a value of 6.

This formula works the other way round:

=INDEX(A1:I1,MATCH(1,INDEX(1-ISBLANK(A1:I1),1,0),0)

But I can’t figure out how to flip it so that it goes from the other side. Also it would count a value of 0 which I want to ignore.

Does any body have any idea how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **value** will be given by:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(1:1>0),1:1)
```

The **location** *(column number)* will be given by the Array Formula:

```
=IF(COUNTA(1:1)=0,"",MAX((1:1<>0)*(COLUMN(1:1))))
```

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

[image]

Comment: Perfect thanks - haven't used or seen the lookup function before so this is really helpful :)

Comment: To get the location you can also use `MATCH` with a similar syntax to the `LOOKUP` - i.e. `=MATCH(2,1/(1:1>0))` - confirm with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER